# Why not use java.util.logging?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

For the first time in my life I find myself in a position where I'm writing a Java API that will be open sourced. Hopefully to be included in many other projects.

For logging I (and indeed the people I work with) have always used JUL (`java.util.logging`) and never had any issues with it. However now I need to understand in more detail what I should do for my API development. I've done some research on this and with the information I've got I just get more confused. Hence this post.

Since I come from JUL I'm biased on that. My knowledge of the rest is not that big.

From the research I've done I've come up with these reasons why people do not like JUL:

1. *"I started developing in Java long before Sun released JUL and it was just easier for me to continue with logging-framework-X rather than to learn something new"*. Hmm. I'm not kidding, this is actually what people say. With this argument we could all be doing COBOL. (however I can certainly relate to this being a lazy dude myself)
2. *"I don't like the names of the logging levels in JUL"*. Ok, seriously, this is just not enough of a reason to introduce a new dependency.
3. *"I don't like the standard format of the output from JUL"*. Hmm. This is just configuration. You do not even have to do anything code-wise. (true, back in old days you may have had to create your own Formatter class to get it right).
4. *"I use other libraries that also use logging-framework-X so I thought it easier just to use that one"*. This is a circular argument, isn't ? Why does 'everybody' use logging-framework-X and not JUL?
5. *"Everybody else is using logging-framework-X"*. This to me is just a special case of the above. Majority is not always right.

So the real big question is **why not JUL?**. What is it I have missed ? The raison d'être for logging facades (SLF4J, JCL) is that multiple logging implementations have existed historically and the reason for that really goes back to the era before JUL as I see it. If JUL was perfect then logging facades wouldn't exist, or what? To make matters more confusing JUL is to some extent a facade itself, allowing Handlers, Formatters and even the LogManager to be swapped.

Rather than embracing multiple ways of doing the same thing (logging), shouldn't we question why they were necessary in the first place? (and see if those reasons still exist)

Ok, my research so far has led to a couple of things that I can see may be **real issues** with JUL:

1. **Performance**. Some say that performance in SLF4J is superior to the rest. This seems to me to be a case of premature optimization. If you need to log hundreds of megabytes per second then I'm not sure you are on the right path anyway. JUL has also evolved and the tests you did on Java 1.4 may no longer be true. You can read about it [here](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.dk/2009/04/faster-logging-with-faster-logger.html) and this fix has made it into Java 7. Many also talk about the overhead of string concatenation in logging methods. However template based logging avoids this cost and it exist also in JUL. Personally I never really write template based logging. Too lazy for that. For example if I do this with JUL:

   ```
    log.finest("Lookup request from username=" + username 
       + ", valueX=" + valueX
       + ", valueY=" + valueY));
   ```

   my IDE will warn me and ask permission that it should change it to:

   ```
    log.log(Level.FINEST, "Lookup request from username={0}, valueX={1}, valueY={2}", 
       new Object[]{username, valueX, valueY});
   ```

   .. which I will of course accept. Permission granted ! Thank you for your help.

   So I don't actually write such statements myself, that is done by the IDE.

   In conclusion on the issue of performance I haven't found anything that would suggest that JUL's performance is not ok compared to the competition.
2. **Configuration from classpath**. Out-of-the-box JUL cannot load a configuration file from the classpath. It is a [few lines of code](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4958543) to make it do so. I can see why this may be annoying but the solution is short and simple.
3. **Availability of output handlers**. JUL comes with 5 output handlers out-of-the-box: console, file stream, socket and memory. These can be extended or new ones can be written. This may for example be writing to UNIX/Linux Syslog and Windows Event Log. I have personally never had this requirement nor have I seen it used but I can certainly relate to why it may be a useful feature. Logback comes with an appender for Syslog for example. Still I would argue that

   1. 99.5% of the needs for output destinations are covered by what is in JUL out-of-the-box.
   2. Special needs could be catered for by custom handlers on top of JUL rather than on top of something else. There's nothing to me that suggests that it takes more time to write a Syslog output handler for JUL than it does for another logging framework.

I'm really concerned that there's something I've overlooked. The use of logging facades  and logging implementations other than JUL is so widespread that I have to come to the conclusion that it's me who just doesn't understand. That wouldn't be the first time, I'm afraid. :-)

So what should I do with my API?  I want it to become successful.  I can of course just "go with the flow" and implement SLF4J (which seems the most popular these days) but for my own sake I still need to understand exactly what is wrong with the JUL of today that warrants all the fuzz?  Will I sabotage myself by choosing JUL for my library ?

### Testing performance

*(section added by nolan600 on 07-JUL-2012)*

There's a reference below from Ceki about SLF4J's parametrization being 10 times or more faster than JUL's. So I've started doing some simple tests. At first glance the claim is certainly correct. Here are the preliminary results (but read on!):

- Execution time SLF4J, backend Logback: 1515
- Execution time SLF4J, backend JUL: 12938
- Execution time JUL: 16911

The numbers above are msecs so less is better. So 10 times performance difference is by first actually pretty close. My initial reaction: That is a lot !

Here is the core of the test. As can be seen an integer and a string is construted in a loop which is then used in the log statement:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfExecutions; i++) {
        for (char x=32; x<88; x++) {
            String someString = Character.toString(x);
            // here we log 
        }
    }
```

(I wanted the log statement to have both a primitive data type (in this case an int) and a more complex data type (in this case a String). Not sure it matters but there you have it.)

The log statement for SLF4J:

```
logger.info("Logging {} and {} ", i, someString);
```

The log statement for JUL:

```
logger.log(Level.INFO, "Logging {0} and {1}", new Object[]{i, someString});
```

The JVM was 'warmed up' with the same test executed once before the actual measurement was done. Java 1.7.03 was used on Windows 7. Latest versions of SLF4J (v1.6.6) and Logback (v1.0.6) was used. Stdout and stderr was redirected to null device.

However, careful now, it turns out JUL is spending most of its time in `getSourceClassName()` because JUL by default prints the source class name in the output, while Logback doesn't. So we are comparing apples and oranges. I have to do the test again and configure the logging implementations in a similar manner so that they actually output the same stuff. I do however suspect that SLF4J+Logback will still come out on top but far from the initial numbers as given above. Stay tuned.

Btw: The test was first time I've actually worked with SLF4J or Logback. A pleasant experience. JUL is certainly a lot less welcoming when you are starting out.

### Testing performance (part 2)

*(section added by nolan600 on 08-JUL-2012)*

As it turns out it doesn't really matter for performance how you configure your pattern in JUL, i.e. whether or not it includes the source name or not. I tried with a very simple pattern:

```
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format="%4$s: %5$s [%1$tc]%n"
```

and that did not change the above timings at all. My profiler revealed that the logger still spent a lot of time in calls to `getSourceClassName()` even if this was not part of my pattern. The pattern doesn't matter.

I'm therefore concluding on the issue of performance that at least for the tested template based log statement there seems to be roughly a factor of 10 in real performance difference between JUL (slow) and SLF4J+Logback (quick). Just like Ceki said.

I can also see another thing namely that SLF4J's `getLogger()` call is a lot more expensive than JUL's ditto. (95 ms vs 0.3 ms if my profiler is accurate). This makes sense. SLF4J has to do some time on the binding of the underlying logging implementation. This doesn't scare me. These calls should be somewhat rare in the lifetime of an application. The fastness should be in the actual log calls.

## Final conclusion

*(section added by peterh on 08-JUL-2012)*

Thank you for all your answers. Contrary to what I initially thought I've ended up deciding to use SLF4J for my API. This is based on a number of things and your input:

1. It gives flexibility to choose log implementation at deployment time.
2. Issues with lack of flexibility of JUL's configuration when run inside an application server.
3. SLF4J is certainly a lot faster as detailed above in particular if you couple it with Logback. Even if this was just a rough test I have reason to believe that a lot more effort has gone into optimization on SLF4J+Logback than on JUL.
4. Documentation. The documentation for SLF4J is simply a lot more comprehensive and precise.
5. Pattern flexibility. As I did the tests I set out to have JUL mimic the default pattern from Logback. This pattern includes the name of the thread. It turns out JUL cannot do this out of the box. Ok, I haven't missed it until now, but I don't think it is a thing that should be missing from a log framework. Period!
6. Most (or many) Java projects today use Maven so adding a dependency is not that big a thing especially if that dependency is rather stable, i.e. doesn't constantly change its API. This seems to be true for SLF4J. Also the SLF4J jar and friends are small in size.

So the strange thing that happened was that I actually got quite upset with JUL after having worked a bit with SLF4J. I still regret that it has to be this way with JUL. JUL is far from perfect but kind of does the job. Just not quite well enough. The same can be said about `Properties` as an example but we do not think about abstracting that so people can plug in their own configuration library and what have you. I think the reason is that `Properties` comes in just above the bar while the opposite is true for JUL of today ... and in the past it came in at zero because it didn't exist.

## Final-final conclusion (maybe)

*(section added by peterh on 02-OCT-2022)*

Java 9 introduced the [System.Logger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.Logger.html) which is intended as a facade to logging implementations. Hence, as far as I can tell, it competes with SLF4J, but has the advantage that it is included with the JDK. **So perhaps library developers should use System.Logger rather than SLF4J** ?

I find [this blog post](https://renato.athaydes.com/posts/java-system-logging.htm) by Renato Athaydes to explain it quite well. (btw: the bug in the Log4j-v2 bridge mentioned by Renato seems to have been [fixed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1360) with v2.13.2 of Log4j v2)

Comment: I won't ask a closing, as this well presented question is interesting, but it's borderline if you read the FAQ : it will be hard to find a definitive unique answer not based on opinions.

Comment: What you may have missed is that many framework authors gave up trying to use JUL and thus it's often harder to use it if you don't simply make vanilla java.

Comment: Thanks, dystroy, I'm aware that it is difficult to find a unique answer. I'll reward the answer badge to the one that comes up with the one or several compelling reasons why I should not go with the JUL of today. This reason/reasons _must_ exist, otherwise all these facades and logging implementations wouldn't be in use.

Comment: It is misleading to use the generic term "logging-framework-X" when referring to to popular logging framework(s) predating jul. You should use "log4j" in this case. Other popular frameworks such as SLF4J and logback came well after j.u.l was released.

Comment: There is one output handler that is very useful.  The one that sends a mail with the previous X log entries whenever a given criteria is full-filled.  That is quite useful when triaging.

Comment: You should use .logp in order to avoid getSourceClassName call

Comment: peterh or @Ceki, if you can add a comment on how things changed in the las 4 years, this would make this question/answers a lot more valuable.

Comment: @Acuariano. I've done a couple of APIs since then and only used SLF4J directly in one of these. Since then Netty project has taught me a way to create an API which is independent of all these logging preferences that people may have. I think that is the way forward for APIs.

Comment: Any pointers, reference or links on how that would go?

Comment: @Acuariano. Netty project is simply using Reflection to test what logging framework is available on classpath. See [here](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/internal/logging) for source. See `InternalLoggerFactory.java`.

Comment: One more reason against SLF4J/log4j: Broken by design for modularized classloading. We use JBoss Modules / Forge in our project, and log4j simply looks for log4j.properties resource through a classloader, so it ends up with one from any dependency. Which is typically not only wrong one, but also it's not deterministic - because modules loading is parallelized. So you end up with broken logging, and it's broken differently each time.

Comment: No matter which java framework you use today, the core of it was written by @Ceki . JUL diverged around Java 1.4. The reasons for re-architecting were laid out in a 1999 article by Ceki.  With Ceki's answer, you have the answer of someone who has essentially done nothing but engineer java logging solutions for 20 years +/-, and who actually wrote most of the viable alternatives.

Comment: nice! question? any chance though you could modernize it for Java 8? since java 8 updated the JUL APIs... (specifically looking at performance analysis, and maybe trying to get people to look at the points like JUL supports callbacks, but SLF4j doesn't.

Comment: @xenoterracide even more important would be an update to Java 9, as it introduced `java.lang.System.Logger`, which is an *interface*, which can be redirected to whatever actual logging framework you want, as long as that framework caught up and provides an implementation of that interface. Combined with the modularization, you could even deploy an application with a bundled JRE not containing `java.util.logging`, if you prefer a different framework.

Comment: Link to `java.lang.System.Logger`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.Logger.html

Comment: Considering JUL can be redirected to other backends, why not check how it being redirected to slf4j or other facades would perform?

Answer (score 255, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I am the founder of log4j, SLF4J and logback projects.

There are objective reasons for preferring SLF4J. For one, **SLF4J allows the end-user the liberty to choose the underlying logging framework**. In addition, savvier users tend to prefer [logback which offers capabilities beyond log4j](http://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html), with j.u.l falling way behind. Feature-wise j.u.l  may be sufficient for some users but for many others it just isn't. In a nutshell, if logging is important to you, you would want to use SLF4J with logback as the underlying implementation. If logging is unimportant, j.u.l is fine.

However, as an oss developer, you need to take into account the preferences of your users and not just your own. It follows that you should adopt SLF4J not because *you* are convinced that SLF4J is better than j.u.l but because most Java developers currently (July 2012) prefer SLF4J as their logging API. If ultimately you decide not to care about popular opinion, consider the following facts:

1. those who prefer j.u.l do so out of convenience because j.u.l is bundled with the JDK. To my knowledge there are no other objective arguments in favor of j.u.l.
2. your own preference for j.u.l is just that, *a preference*.

Thus, holding "hard facts" above public opinion, while seemingly brave, is a logical fallacy in this case.

If still not convinced, [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) makes an additional and potent argument:

> Except the end user could have already done this customization for his
>   own code, or another library that uses log4j or logback. j.u.l is
>   extensible, but having to extend logback, j.u.l, log4j and God only
>   knows which other logging framework because he uses four libraries that
>   use four different logging frameworks is cumbersome. By using SLF4J, you
>   allow him to configure the logging frameworks he wants, not the one
>   you have chosen. **Remember that a typical project uses myriads of
>   libraries, and not just yours**.

If for whatever reason you hate the SLF4J API and using it will snuff the fun out of your work, then by all means go for j.u.l. After all, there are means to [redirect j.u.l to SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j).

By the way, j.u.l parametrization is at least 10 times slower than SLF4J's which ends up making a noticeable difference.

Comment: @Ceki you may want to elaborate a bit on your disclaimer so it mentions your current role in the log4j, slf4j and logback projects.  The reason is naturally to explain your bias.

Comment: Is there some support for the claim that most Java developers prefer SLF4J as their logging API?

Comment: The essence of my post is that different developers have different preferences which seems beyond dispute. Yes?

Comment: I'm wondering will JDK adopt slf4j as part of it in the future.

Comment: Another objective argument for j.u.l. is if you want the smallest download size for your Java app as possible, it will be smaller if you use j.u.l instead of bundling SLF4J or whatever with it.  It seems like Java is mostly just used for enterprise software these days, so people tend to forget this...

Comment: Also, j.u.l. added support in 1.8 for `Supplier`s for generating log messages, which provides infinite flexibility in creating log messages without sacrificing disabled logging performance -- does SLF4J have a functional solution like that or only format string logging?

Comment: If I recall, wasn't the original release of JUL a buggy hack of log4j? Then JCL was a hasty attempt to blindly support a common API in response to and before Sun released the JUL?

Comment: Objective argument in favor of JUL see @Andy's comment, SLF4J doesn't support it (I know I've been following that bug for years).

Comment: honestly though, I'd love to see 2018 benchmarks on  Java 11 (or whatever that ends up being), and against log4j2 in async mode.

Comment: Here I am, using SLF4J, and I *still* have to deal with all the other logging frameworks other libraries use. Using SLF4J does not solve the problem of heterogeneous loggers, it just makes it worse. https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: LOL, I had to debug a project that used SLF4J yesterday. The logging functions did nothing, and determining why was impossible. java.util.logging failed too. So I resorted to writing a class that opens a file in append mode (which, like logging, Java turns into a Hard Problem that involves a quarter-dozen objects). Now I'm debugging another Java project and logging doesn't work there, either! And I already deleted the other project, so I'll end up rewriting my file-appender from scratch. What I'm not going to do is try to add SLF4J to the project.

Comment: SLF4J forces transient dependencies on my end users (as a library). This transient dependency may collide with other libraries they are using, or versions of the library provided by for example an application server. The question this answer misses to address is IMO: is there a difference between OSS libraries, inhouse libraries/tools and applications? Should SLF4J be the go-to for any of these? Because a lot of libraries seem to prefer JUL still.

Comment: @Jan-WillemGmeligMeyling what transient dependencies? slf4j-api is 62K and has no dependencies...

Comment: @Ceki et all - how does slf4 compares to System.Logger? They do seem to overlapt, the latter (or rather it's JEP) states it not intended as common logging facade/framework but it's hard not to consider it as such...

Comment: @wojtek From the perspective of the application using the library, slf4j-api is the transitive dependency

Answer (score 37):

1. `java.util.logging` was introduced in Java 1.4. There were uses for logging before that. That's why many other logging APIs exist. Those APIs were used heavily before Java 1.4 and thus had a great market share that didn't just drop to zero when 1.4 was release.
2. JUL didn't start out all that great. Many of the things you mentioned were a lot worse in 1.4 and only got better in 1.5 (and I guess in 6 as well, but I'm not too sure).
3. JUL isn't well suited for multiple applications with different configurations in the same JVM (think multiple web applications that should not interact). Tomcat needs to jump through some hoops to get that working (effectively re-implementing JUL if I understood that correctly).
4. You can't always influence what logging framework your libraries use. Therefore using SLF4J (which is actually just a very thin API layer above other libraries) helps keep a somewhat consistent picture of the entire logging world (so you can decide the underlying logging framework while still having library logging in the same system).
5. Libraries can't easily change. If a previous version of a library used to use logging-library-X it can't easily switch to logging-library-Y (for example JUL), even if the latter is clearly superior. Any user of that library would need to learn the new logging framework and (at least) reconfigure their logging. That's a big no-no, especially when it brings no apparent gain to most people.

Having said all that I think JUL is *at least* a valid alternative to other logging frameworks these days.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, I appreciate your post. Your (1) and (2) are to me just history. Long time ago. Your (4) is a consequence of that and then becomes what I call a cyclic argument. Your (3) is however really interesting. Maybe you are on to something? But this would only affect those who are building application containers which at the end of the day is very few people. Or what?

Comment: Well, who ignores history is doomed to repeate it ;-) History is **very** relevant in software development. People don't move too fast and replacing existing third-party libraries with standard APIs *only* works well if the standard APIs work *at least* as good as the third-party libraries. And they didn't initially (and arguably still don't in some cases).

Comment: Joachim,I'm interested in those "arguably still don't in some cases" that you mention. That's were the meat has got to be. Replacing a logger library in your existing code is pretty trivial and can be automated these days. SLF4J has a tool for that which kind of proves my point. So I would think that a massive library written in 2002 with log4j could be converted to JUL in a matter of minutes with an automated tool. (I don't know if one exist, though). So why doesn't it happen?

Comment: @nolan6000: I don't know enough about the specifics to go into details about that phrase, and it's not really the point I'm making. Even if JUL is now on par with third-party frameworks, inertia and existing infrastructure is still a strong reason not to switch. For example if library X used slf4j in Version 1.1, switching to JUL in 1.2 (or even 2.0) would be a major problem for many users (who already correctly configured the old system and would have to re-do that for no apparent gain).

Comment: @nolan6000 even if _you_ do not care about history, the _libraries_ you use in your applications most certainly do.  No fun in having to discard a library simply because it used a different logging framework than you.

Comment: @nolan6000 and using an automated tool to change the logging framework used in a given library (either by source or in - shudders - the binary) completely defies any efforts spent in using Maven or another dependency management tool.

Comment: Point 3 here is still the most pertinent - it's precisely _because_ j.u.l is part of the platform that puts it at an immediate disadvantage.  Any other logging frameworks you can have different frameworks or different versions of the same framework in different classloaders with independent configuration, but j.u.l is on the bootstrap classpath so by definition has to be one set of configuration per JVM. The logging framework is something you specifically _don't want_ to be bundled with the JVM.

Answer (score 35):

IMHO, the main advantage in using a logging facade like slf4j is that you let the end-user of the library choose which concrete logging implementation he wants, rather than imposing your choice to the end user.

Maybe he has invested time and money in Log4j or LogBack (special formatters, appenders, etc.) and prefers continuing using Log4j or LogBack, rather than configuring jul. No problem: slf4j allows that. Is it a wise choice to use Log4j over jul? Maybe, maybe not. But you don't care. Let the end user choose what he prefers.

Comment: Thanks JB. My question is if I'm really imposing that much on the user/implementer of my library by forcing JUL on him?  If he's unhappy with for example JUL's standard output handlers he can just swap them for his own at deployment time as I see it. I don't really see JUL as a straitjacket. It seems to me to be as flexible and extendible as the rest of them.

Comment: Except the end user could have already done this customization for his own code, or another library that uses log4j or LogBack. jul is extensible, but having to extend LogBack, jul, log4j and God only knows which other logging framework because he uses 4 libraries that use 4 different logging frameworks is cumbersome. By using slf4j, you allow him to configure the logging frameworks he wants. not the one you have chosen. Remember that typical projects use myriads of libraries, and not just yours.

Answer (score 9):

I started, like you I suspect, using JUL because it was the easiest one to get going immediately. Over the years, however, I have come to wish I had spent a little more time choosing.

My main issue now is that we have a substantial amount of 'library' code that is used in many applications and they all use JUL. Whenever I use these tools in a web-service type app the logging just disappears or goes somewhere unpredictable or strange.

Our solution was to add a facade to the library code that meant that the library log calls did not change but were dynamically redirected to whatever logging mechanism is available. When included in a POJO tool they are directed to JUL but when deployed as a web-app they are redirected to LogBack.

Our regret - of course - is that the library code does not use parameterised logging but this can now be retrofitted as and when needed.

We used slf4j to build the facade.

Comment: Any reason you did not just use the "redirect java.util.logging to slf4j" package in the slf4j distribution?

Comment: We did, but to little value because the primary benefit of moving to slf4j is efficient parameterised logging. If we'd used that from the start we would not have had any work to do now.

Comment: I agree that this is the low hanging fruit of slf4j.

Answer (score 3):

I ran jul against slf4j-1.7.21 over logback-1.1.7, output to an SSD, Java 1.8, Win64

jul ran 48449 ms, logback 27185 ms for an 1M loop.

Still, a little more speed and a bit nicer API is not worth 3 libraries and 800K for me.

```
package log;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class LogJUL
{
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LogJUL.class.getSimpleName());

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int N = 1024*1024;

        long l = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            Long lc = System.currentTimeMillis();

            Object[] o = { lc };

            logger.log(Level.INFO,"Epoch time {0}", o);
        }

        l = System.currentTimeMillis() - l;

        System.out.printf("time (ms) %d%n", l);
    }
}
```

and

```
package log;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class LogSLF
{
    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogSLF.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int N = 1024*1024;

        long l = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            Long lc = System.currentTimeMillis();

            logger.info("Epoch time {}", lc);
        }

        l = System.currentTimeMillis() - l;

        System.out.printf("time (ms) %d%n", l);
    }

}
```

Comment: You're not comparing like for like. Why are you explicitly creating an array for j.u.l.? I guess it's because slf4j lacks a one-argument overload of `logger.info()`. So you're deliberately crippling j.u.l. performance to compensate for a shortcoming in slf4j's interface. You should instead code both methods the way they are idiomatically coded.

Comment: You misunderstood it. You don't have to use an additional 800K. The consensus is that the **very thin** SLF4J api is worth to use because then you (or others who maybe reuse one day your code!) can switch freely among JUL, Logback, Log4j etc. SLF4J is only ~28K. SLF4J to JUL bridge (slf4j-jdk...jar) is only ~9K.

Answer (score -1):

Reasons why not JUL:

1. User-unfriendly API design - The clumsy message arguments syntax, the strange definition of log levels... The list goes on.
2. It is a logging implementation and not a Facade.

As the quoted blog post points out, it is a NON-goal of Java 9 System.Logger either to define a general-purpose interface for logging. Both SLF4J and Apache Commons Logging have attempted such Facade goal but IMHO both failed by providing too much implementation instead of sticking to the simple goal of a well-defined logging facade. E.g., a real logging facade would never be compared to any logging implementation on "performance" because a facade itself isn't expected to be logging.

Disclaimer: For logging facade, I re-invent the wheel and use my own - https://github.com/elf4j/elf4j/

Comment: Counter: It is indeed a stated non-goal of `System.Logger`. Yet, proponents argue that it actually fills the role. It does have the huge advantage that it is always available. So alternative logging facades (slf4j, elf4j, etc) will have an uphill battle arguing why their implementation is vastly superior to `System.Logger`. Will be interesting to follow.

Comment: True on the convinience factor for System.Logger. 

As per reasons why use it for its non-goal, it's a matter of opinion and everybody has one. 

As an API user, my main thing is always the API design's user-friendliness. System.Logger API is friendlier than JUL but these are still unfriendly to use: A. Numbered, instead of position-based, placeholder for message args; B. Inconsistent argument-supply syntax between log methods that take Throwable arg vs. those that don't. C. ResourceBundle syntactically appears in API instead of "convention offline".

Comment: @q3769 just to point out regarding the numbered-based placeholders - it's a big advantage in cases where you would use translations, and so in general I find it superior. I'm not sure there's a case for it in logging, but who knows.

Comment: @MorBlau the issue I had with using number-based placeholder in logging was it took much more time when you need to change positions of message args. E.g. when you have 5 args originally, and you want to drop the 2nd, move the 5th to the 3rd, and swap the 1st and 4th, all at the same time... Having to carry the index numbers and make sure they line up correctly becomes a drag rather than help - it's much easier to just read though the natural language order with positional/empty holders. Just my personal take but that was a big reason I stopped using JUL logging API.

Comment: It doesn’t matter whether your placeholders contain numbers or not. In either case, the changes to the argument list require an adaptation to the message format. If your format string without indices doesn’t line up with the arguments, the result will be a mess too. In the end, you are not independent of the back-end if you have to encode assumptions about the back-end’s formatter. The only reasonable logging API is taking a just a `String` or `Supplier<String>`. No ambiguity. Your supplier can use whatever formatting API you prefer or just a string concatenation.

Comment: It matters quite a bit for coding time needed to reconcile multiple arguments and change the entire log message structure: Saves ~50% time with positional (non-numbered) placeholders per my own experience. Much agreed logging argument substitution is not about formatting: Not the best of ideas trying to couple the two different concerns, as in most logging APIs. I disagree, though, that String and Supplier are the only reasonable logging argument types: As long as the logging API does not try to format the arguments after substitution, it should be fine.