# The logp doesn`t print

Tags: java, logging

When I run this code, nothing is printed to the console. How should I use logp?

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Log {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Logger.getGlobal().logp(Level.ALL, Log.class.getName(), "main", "t");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logger doesn't print the message because of too low logging level. `ALL` is usually used for configuring loggers, not for actual logging. Change the logging level to `INFO` and you'll see your message:

```
Logger.getGlobal().logp(Level.INFO, Log.class.getName(), "main", "t");
```

Also, read something on JUL. For instance, [good examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950557/good-examples-using-java-util-logging) and [why not use JUL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359187/why-not-use-java-util-logging).