# How to configure java util logging in jetty server

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-9

Followed this [link](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.11.v20180605/configuring-logging-modules.html#example-logging-java-util-logging) to configure java util logging with slf4j. All steps mentioned there were executed without error, but data logged with java util logger from webapp were not there in main log file, also there was no separate file created for the same.

I am using jetty-distribution-9.4.11.v20180605 server on my ubuntu 16.04.

Can anyone please help me to configure java util logging

Comment: Why on earth would you want to use the worst logging framework possible?

Comment: @Kayaman Can you please suggest me better framework available then?

Comment: I'd go with Logback or Log4J2. JUL is [pretty much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359187/why-not-use-java-util-logging) the worst "proper" logging framework in existence.